Linux IP Implementation - reordering of packets
I'm studying how TCP works in Linux. "TCP uses a sequence number to identify each byte of data. The sequence number identifies the order of the bytes sent from each computer so that the data can be reconstructed in order, regardless of any out-of-order delivery that may occur. The sequence number of the first byte is chosen by the transmitter for the first packet, which is flagged SYN. This number can be arbitrary, and should, in fact, be unpredictable to defend against TCP sequence prediction attacks."
What algorithm does linux use to reassembly any out of sequence packets? A priority queue? Could I ask for help locating the code reference?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol

Here is the source code for the IPv4 TCP implementation in the Linux Kernel.
The parent directory (ipv4) contains a number of additional files related to the TCP implementation.
And here is an (old) paper discussing the general TCP implementation in Linux.
